# Searching hyphenated words with Lucene

Tags: lucene

I want lucene to search for hyphenated words, 
for eg: energy-efficient or "energy-efficient" as one single word

So if the input is energy-efficient the tokenizer generates terms like
energy or efficient or energy efficient or energy-efficient

Therefore lucene returns with pages containing both "energy efficient" and "energy-efficient", but I want it to return exclusively with pages for energy-efficient

So the question is how can I modify the standardtokenizer to search for energy-efficient as one whole word and not break it into separate words.

Answer (score 11):

Use `WhitespaceAnalyzer` instead of `standardAnalyzer`.
That will generate tokens dividing only on white space. But check for the other things that'll be changed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! There isn't much documentation about these things. I have a custom `Analyzer` to prevent stop words from being filtered, so I'm now using a `WhitespaceTokenizer` instead of the `StandardTokenizer` in my analyzer. Beware though, when using a `WhitespaceTokenizer`, the searching becomes case sensitive. So I had to wrap it through a `LowerCaseFilter` first.

Comment: I fear not! Whitespace analyser is very accurately named: "bubble" is counted as an entirely different token to "bubble:", for example.  For 99% of cases this is not of much use... and I don't think it's of use to the OP

Answer (score 0):

Here is my complete blog on [Lucene and Hyphen](http://pvrworld-lucene.blogspot.com/) 
If you want to give support of HYPHEN in `StandardAnalyzer` then you have to make changes in `StandardTokenizerImpl` which is responsible for tokenization. 
 
 StandardTokenizer breaks hyphenated words into two for example "energy-efficient" is tokenized as energy,efficient.

As `StandardTokenizerImpl.java` is generated class from [jFlex](http://jflex.de/) and its input file is `StandardTokenizerImpl.jflex` you have to add following line in `SUPPLEMENTARY.jflex-macro` which is included by `StandardTokenizerImpl.jflex`

```
            MidLetterSupp = ( [\u002D]  )
```

After that generate the StandardTokenizerImpl.java using jflex and rebuild the index.